# Python extension package wordcloud not be installed correctly

Tags: python

While I loaded the python extension package wordcloud it showed the
"No module named 'wordcloud'" message, then I think it is a regular error happened to the scripts, so I installed the updated version of .whl file from wordcloud, but it cannot be pip installed correctly as attached picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35QVm.png)

Comment: It's spelled `wordcloud`. And check your distribution, you are trying to install and `amd64` version.

Comment: Thanks for your correction and I will try it.

Comment: There is a difference between `pip` and `pip3` on linux as well...

Comment: Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32, this is my version

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using Anaconda. Try to run this:

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge wordcloud`